# Trying to sort a JSON by its field raises TypeError

Tags: python

I have been working on a Python Program that takes the data from an API, and then stores it in a `.json` file, it then sorts through and finds the weekend, with the current time. If the WaveHeight is above 2.00, it will then send an email.

So far it has been alright, the email system works, but the only thing that doesn't is this section -

```
sorted(data, key = lambda i: i['hours']) #sorts through cache_file data 
print([0])
```

I get this error when I run the script -

```
sorted (data, key = lambda i: i['hours']) #sorts through cache_file data
# TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I have tried a bunch of things, but I feel like I am missing a tiny little thing that is stopping this from working.

If there is anything else that you need to help debug this problem, just ask...

EDIT: Here is a Gist of the code, with private info redacted. https://gist.github.com/Xioto/4b7979f5fef0f4d646b03555811229ac

Here is the `response.json` as well.
https://gist.github.com/Xioto/00f05431e2e9a2cb6888728ea97ca101

Comment: Can you show how `data` looks like?

Comment: It is not a direct answer, but here is a gist of the code, with private info redacted.  https://gist.github.com/Xioto/4b7979f5fef0f4d646b03555811229ac

Comment: Looks like you’re trying to sort a raw JSON string. You’ll probably have to do your sort on what consists of a `list` of `dict` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking to sort `data`, which is a JSON that looks like this :

```json
data = {
  "hours": [
    {
      "time": "2021-06-12T00:00:00+00:00",
      "waveHeight": {
        "dwd": 0.25,
        "fcoo": 0.43,
        "icon": 0.54,
        "meteo": 0.44,
        "noaa": 0.71,
        "sg": 0.43
      }
    }
    ...  # many others
  ],
}
```

So Python tries to sort `data`, which is a dictionnary, so it fetches the keys and provide them to your lambda. But :

```py
>>> data.keys()
dict_keys(['hours'])
```

All the keys of the dictionnary consists of a list of only one item, `"hour"`. So the string `hours` is provided to your lambda, which tries to get its `"hours"`-th character, which does not work because `string indices must be integers`.

You are making two mistakes with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) :

- first you should assign the return value, because `sorted` is not [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)
- second your key lambda is incorrect, its role is to retrieve the key on which to sort, so for "wave elements" (having a time and an height), because you want to sort them in ascending time, it should return the `time` value for a wave.

Here is a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem (that I used to diagnose) :

```py
data = {
  "hours": [
    {
      "time": "2021-06-12T00:00:00+00:00",
      "waveHeight": {
        "dwd": 0.25,
        "fcoo": 0.43,
        "icon": 0.54,
        "meteo": 0.44,
        "noaa": 0.71,
        "sg": 0.43
      }
    }
  ],
}

sorted(data, key = lambda i: i['hours']) #sorts through cache_file data 
print([0])
```

and here is the correct version :

```py
waves = sorted(
    data["hours"],  # I'm sorting the list of wave data contained in the JSON
    key=lambda wave: wave["time"]  # according to their respective "time" attribute
)
print(waves[0])
```